# PHP: Unlink resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, delete-file, unlink

I'm trying to delete a file after it is uploaded via a form and processed:

```
// FORM SUBMIT
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $uploadfile = getcwd() . '/pub/media/dealers/' . basename($_FILES['proof']['name']);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['proof']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

    // Upload attachment to Zendesk
    $attachment = $client->attachments()->upload([
      'file' => $uploadfile
    ]);

    unlink($uploadfile);
    exit;
}
```

I receive the following error:

> Error filtering template: Warning:
>   unlink(C:....\MyFile.txt): Resource
>   temporarily unavailable

If I remove the `$attachment` upload code, then the file is deleted as expected. So I've tried the following, but receive the same Temporarily Unavailable error:

```
$attachment = $client->attachments()->upload([
    'file' => $uploadfile
  ]);

unset($attachment);
unlink($uploadfile);
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try unset($client); instead of attachment

Comment: Thanks @LuísChaves, tried that but received the same error

Comment: add this before unlink gc_collect_cycles();

Comment: ah that was it, `unset($client)` instead of `$attachment` and then adding `gc_collect_cycles();` , thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (file_exists(public_path($category->image))) 
                {
                    unlink(public_path($category->image));
                }

   'It gives the same error in the above code, but if it fixes it as follows, we do not get the following error:'

if(!empty($category->image)){
        if (file_exists(public_path($category->image))) {
            unlink(public_path($category->image));
        }
        }

`The file we are going to update should not be empty.`
```